# Using tag-specific CSS selectors in GWT CssResources

Tags: gwt

My question is whether it's possible to use CSS selectors for typical HTML elements (e.g. "p" or "table") in CssResource stylesheets. And btw can pseudo-selectors like :hover be used? Or does the compiler just obfuscate everything?

Comment: What have you tried? It should be pretty easy to test the cases you mentioned yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, now that I've tested a little, as Igor Klimer requested, I found out that the tag-specific selectors work the way they should and that pseudo-selectors can also be used. I hope that will be useful for someone googling this question in the future.

Edit: Even CSS3 Animations work perfectly fine

Comment: Thanks for following up on this :) You can even mark this answer as accepted ([after 48 hours](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/)).

Comment: That's nice to know (: No problem, I could have done so from the start, but I thought maybe someone already tested it and I could rather ask ^^